# Grammar file (grammar.txt)

Tags: file, grammar, ttcn

I am actually working on a grammar file and I am reading the grammar.txt file.

The 20 first lines are new to me.

```
%s/^\d*\.\s*(\w*)
%s/^\d*\.\s*\(\w*\)
%s/^\d*\.\s*\(\w*\)/<\1>
%s/^\d*\.\s*\(\w*\)/\1
%s/\<\(\w*\)\>
%s/"\w*\" 
%s/"\(\w*\)\"/_\1_/g
%s/"\(\w*\)\"/&\1&/g
%s/"\(\w*\)\"/123456\1/g
%s/"\(\w*\)\"/**\1**/g
%s/"\(.*\)\"/$\1$/g
%s/"\(\w*\)\"/$\1$/g
%s/"/'/g
%s/'\(\w*\)'\/$\1$/g
```

Does anyone know what this lines refers to?

Comment: [Regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Could you detail a little bit more please ? Are those lines regex rules ?

Comment: I haven't provided much information as I'm not 100% sure myself. Just looking at them, my mind initially springs to think of Regular Expressions. It'd be nice to get some proper clarification though! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like list of replacement rules someone tried to run in [vim](http://www.vim.org/).
It seems as the someone didn't know how to use it, so was trying to figure it out.

the proper structure is `%s/match/replacement/flags`

- `%s` means search through all lines in the entire file,
- `match` is regular expression that you are looking for,
- `replacement` is what the match will be replaced with,
- `flags` are regexp flags, in this case `g`, which will replace all occurrences at each line.

more info on vim's [search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)